# Not sure if using isset correctly

Tags: php, html

I am building up a website that must not show login option when the user is already logged in, i.e. session is active. I have tried working with this but its not returning the desired output. Please help. Thanks.

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {echo "<li><a href='Employee.php'>Login</a></li>";}
                ?>
```

edit: 
I am adding the part where I check login details from database and start session.

```
 $query = "SELECT Cust_FName from customer where Cust_ID='$name' and  Password='$pass'";


$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!= false)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
echo row[0];
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

echo "Logged in!";
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] = $row[0];
header("Location: index.php");


}


}
```

Comment: you need `session_start()` if you dont have one

Comment: Maybe you should try `if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))` or something like it. $_SESSION is always set, when you have run session_start()!

Comment: Session is active if session_start() is called. You have to call it on each script and it will populate the $_SESSION var with the saved values

Comment: Looks good to me, though you usually check if a part `isset`, nit a whole array, e.g. `if (isset($_SESSION['var_name'])) { /*Do code*/ }`

Comment: I have tried all these ways. I don't exactly get the error I am doing with my code, the login button should only show up when the user has not logged in, and once he does, it should disappear.

Comment: If you want to enforce a condition that a user must not be shown login option if he is already logged in, then you can redirect them to a different page, like this, `if(isset($_SESSION['login'])){ header("Location: some_page.php"); exit(); }`

Comment: FYI, if `$name` and `$pass` are user-submitted data, and you don't do any additional validation, your query could open you up to a SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

From your comment:

> The login button should only show up when the user has not logged in, and once he does, it should disappear.

**Solution**

```
// This would be your login.php page
<?php
    session_start();

    // process your HTML form, like this
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        // Remember: always validate your form inputs
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $pass = $_POST['pass'];

        $query = "SELECT Cust_FName from customer where Cust_ID='$name' and  Password='$pass'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)!= false){
            $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
            //echo row[0];
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                //echo "Logged in!";
                $_SESSION['userName'] = $row[0];
                header("Location: index.php");
                exit(); // exit() is necessary, otherwise the script execution is not terminated. Setting header alone is not enough to redirect.
            }
        }

    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])){
        // user is already logged in
        // redirect the user to a different page
        // header("Location: index.php");
        // exit();
    }else{
        // user is not logged in
        // display login option

        ?>

        <!--Your HTML form for login-->
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" /><br />
            <input type="text" name="pass" value="" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
        </form>

        <?php
    }
?>
```

**Edited:**

Session is a file that resides in our server and in that file we can store any amount of information. We generally deploy a session cookie on the client's browser.

**Before we output any HTML or white space, we need to start our session.**

When we do like this,

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

It will say, go to the browser, get the session id and open the appropriate file and if it didn't find any session id, it will start a new session. User can only see session id, nothing else.

*Tip: Remember to clean up sessions from time to time.*

Comment: Thanks. Did two changes, didn't go for a new page redirection.
Don't know which change basically lead to the right output. 
Added exit() function. 
and before checking isset added @session_start(); 
Its working. Thanks. :)

Comment: As I said in the comment, You should definitely include `exit()` after calling `header("Location: somepage.php")`, otherwise the script execution won't get terminated. Setting a header alone is not enough to redirect. Read the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: And please show your gratitude by accepting an answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the session is started, you can use

```
if(session_status() != PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
    echo "<li><a href='Employee.php'>Login</a></li>";
}
```

The problem is that the session als also there if the user isn't logged in. You have to check if e.g. `$_SESSION['user_id']` is set:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) {
    echo "<li><a href='Employee.php'>Login</a></li>";
}
```

In my example `$_SESSION['user_id']` will be filled when the user login was successful.

Comment: Tried both, my login button that is supposed to disappear once the user logs in, shows all the time. Even though, its displaying the logout button accordingly i.e only when user is logged in it shows the logout button

Comment: Please add the code of user login (the code where you are filling `$_SESSION`) to your question so that we can check it.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the login page

```
<?php
session_start();
// Store Session Data
$_SESSION['login_user']= $username;  // Initializing Session
?>
```

when you have to check use

```
<?php
session_start();
// Store Session Data
if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
    //do things
}
?>
```

and on logout

```
<?php
session_destroy();
?>
```